# Avoiding Error Flags when Reading Files

Tags: c++, while-loop, filestreams

This is how I usually read files with `std::ifstream`:

```
while (InFile.peek() != EOF)
{
    char Character = InFile.get();
    // Do stuff with Character...
}
```

This avoids the need of an `if` statement inside the loop.  However, it seems that even `peek()` causes `eofbit` to be set, which makes calling `clear()` necessary if I plan on using that same stream later.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @Tony I often forget to call InFile.clear()  before doing additional operations later in the program, which causes some hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: @Maxpm: If you're going to re-read the file after EOF, why not just read it into a string, and then copy out into a stringstream and use that for each intermediate operation?

Comment: @DeadMG That would be impractical in my case, as I'm making a file-reading class and maintaining a `stringstream` as a private member would be cumbersome.

Comment: @Maxpm: What, the huge inconvenience of about 20 characters to define it, and some small refactoring, to save yourself hours of debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you would just use

```
char x;
while(file >> x) {
    // do something with x
}
// now clear file if you want
```

If you forget to clear(), then use an RAII scope-based class.

Edit: Given a little more information, I'd just say

```
class FileReader {
    std::stringstream str;
public:
    FileReader(std::string filename) {
        std::ifstream file(filename);
        file >> str.rdbuf();
    }
    std::stringstream Contents() {
        return str;
    }
};
```

Now you can just get a copy and not have to clear() the stream every time. Or you could have a self-clearing reference.

```
template<typename T> class SelfClearingReference {
    T* t;
public:
    SelfClearingReference(T& tref)
        : t(&tref) {}
    ~SelfClearingReference() {
        tref->clear();
    }
    template<typename Operand> T& operator>>(Operand& op) {
        return *t >> op;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand.  `Infile.peek()` only sets `eofbit`
when it returns `EOF`.  And if it returns `EOF`, and later read
is bound to fail; the fact that it sets `eofbit` is an
optimization, more than anything else.

Comment: The idea is that I can use the same stream later on and run through it again (after using `seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg)`), but even then it still needs `clear()` to be called beforehand.